# Get Attribute lable from attribute ID

Tags: magento-1.9, php, static-block

I wondered if you could help with the following? I have a static box which calls a .phtml file.

In this file i am trying to get the `advertiser_name` attribute (which is id 180).

I've managed to put the following code together and it successfully returns "180" but I want it to return the advertiser name, not its number. I can't seem to figure out how I can change this.

**Here's the code**

```
   $productType = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
echo "Test".$productType."<---";

$product_id = $productType;
$_resource = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getResource();
$optionValue = $_resource->getAttributeRawValue($product_id, "advertiser_name", Mage::app()->getStore());
echo $optionValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,Change Your Attribute id

```
<?php
         $getOptionText = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getColor(), 'color');
         $attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute("color");
         if ($attr->usesSource()) {
         $color_label = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($getOptionText);
         }
    ?>
    <div class="color">
         <div class="std"><?php echo $this->__('Color :- ') ?><?php echo $color_label; ?></div>
    </div>
```